# How does Windows 8 Runtime (WinRT / Windows Store apps / Windows 10 Universal App) compare to Silverlight and WPF?

Tags: wpf, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-10, win-universal-app

I am trying to get my head round the new Windows 8 Runtime that is used to create [Metro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metro_%28design_language%29) style apps. I know you can use it with [XAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Application_Markup_Language) and it is based on .NET so C# and VB.NET can be used to write the apps, but then it seems to have something to do with HTML, CSS, DOM, and JavaScript.

Can someone explain what it is in a few paragraphs, in terms that a .NET UI programmer can understand? (I am missing something “key” that is necessary to understand it.)

---

We all know that WPF, [Silverlight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Silverlight), [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms), etc. will keep working under Windows 8 (and Windows 10) on at least on Intel systems, so please don't tell me that...

Comment: It is not based on .NET, only exposed to it (a bit like COM interop, but much more seamless... e.g. no interop assemblies).

Comment: Are you asking for WinRT as the platform (ABI, object model, etc) - in which case it makes more sense to compare it to COM or .NET - or about WinRT standard class libraries, including ones for UI?

Comment: Note that you should distinguish the underlying technology, object model etc - similar to e.g. COM - and specific libraries implemented using that technology. Even in case of the latter, not all standard libraries are UI libraries - if you look in Object Browser in VS, you can see the breadth of features that `Windows.*` namespaces cover.   Terminology so far is somewhat confusing here, as WinRT refers to both the technology and the entire set of standard libraries. I don't think there's any concise label for just the UI libraries (`Windows.UI.*`) though.

Comment: @TrueWill: It makes more sense to learn all three, so that your knowledge will be more well-rounded, and so you can decide which solution is best for a given problem. Don't just learn one of three.

Comment: @TrueWill: Silverlight will not have any future releases: http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft/microsoft-releases-silverlight-5/11391?tag=search-results-rivers;item1

Answer (score 482, accepted):

At the lowest level, WinRT is an object model defined on ABI level. It uses COM as a base (so every WinRT object implements `IUnknown` and does refcounting), and builds from there. It does add quite a lot of new concepts in comparison to COM of old, most of which come directly from .NET - for example, WinRT object model has delegates, and events are done .NET-style (with delegates and add/remove subscriber methods, one per event) rather than the old COM model of event sources and sinks. Of other notable things, WinRT also has parametrized ("generic") interfaces.

One other big change is that all WinRT components have metadata available for them, just like .NET assemblies. In COM you kinda sorta had that with typelibs, but not every COM component had them. For WinRT, the metadata is contained in .winmd files - look inside "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Metadata\" in Developer Preview. If you poke around, you'll see that they are actually CLI assemblies with no code, just metadata tables. You can open them with ILDASM, in fact. Note, this doesn't mean that WinRT itself is managed - it simply reuses the file format.

Then there are a number of libraries implemented in terms of that object model - defining WinRT interfaces and classes. Again, look at "Windows Metadata" folder mentioned above to see what's there; or just fire up Object Browser in VS and select "Windows 8.0" in the framework selector, to see what's covered. There's a lot there, and it doesn't deal with UI alone - you also get namespaces such as `Windows.Data.Json`, or `Windows.Graphics.Printing`, or `Windows.Networking.Sockets`.

Then you get several libraries, which are specifically dealing with UI - mostly these would be various namespaces under `Windows.UI` or `Windows.UI.Xaml`. A lot of them are very similar to WPF/Silverlight namespaces - e.g. `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls` is closely matching `System.Windows.Controls`; ditto for `Windows.UI.Xaml.Documents` etc.

Now, .NET has the ability to directly reference WinRT components as if they were .NET assemblies. This works differently from COM Interop - you don't need any intermediate artifacts such as interop assemblies, you just `/r` a .winmd file, and all types and their members in its metadata become visible to you as if they were .NET objects. Note that WinRT libraries themselves are fully native (and so native C++ programs that use WinRT do not require CLR at all) - the magic to expose all that stuff as managed is inside the CLR itself, and is fairly low level. If you ildasm a .NET program that references a .winmd, you'll see that it actually looks like an extern assembly reference - there's no sleight of hand trickery such as type embedding there.

It's not a blunt mapping, either - CLR tries to adapt WinRT types to their equivalents, where possible. So e.g. GUIDs, dates and URIs become `System.Guid`, `System.DateTime` and `System.Uri`, respectively; WinRT collection interfaces such as `IIterable<T>` and `IVector<T>` become `IEnumerable<T>` and `IList<T>`; and so on. This goes both ways - if you have a .NET object that implements `IEnumerable<T>`, and pass it back to WinRT, it'll see it as `IIterable<T>`.

Ultimately, what this means is that your .NET Metro apps get access to a subset of the existing standard .NET libraries, and also to (native) WinRT libraries, some of which - particularly `Windows.UI` - look very similar to Silverlight, API-wise. You still have XAML to define your UI, and you still deal with the same basic concepts as in Silverlight - data bindings, resources, styles, templates etc. In many cases, it is possible to port a Silverlight app simply by `using` the new namespaces, and tweaking a few places in code where the API was adjusted.

WinRT itself doesn't have anything to do with HTML and CSS, and it bears relation to JavaScript only in a sense that it is also exposed there, similar to how it is done for .NET. You don't need to deal with HTML/CSS/JS when you use WinRT UI libraries in your .NET Metro app (well, I guess, if you really want to, you can host a `WebView` control...). All your .NET and Silverlight skills remain very much relevant in this programming model.

Comment: What about WPF-WinRT compatibility? Will there be WPF-Silverlight sort of inconsistencies?

Comment: @Den WPF is not a good base point of comparison here - the API is much, much closer to Silverlight. If you look at it that way, there are inconsistencies between the two, but the scale is closer to desktop vs WP7 Silverlight, not Silverlight vs WPF.

Comment: Great answer. Does WinRT access the NT kernel directly (when it needs OS support) or does it go through Win32 ?

Comment: Slight correction/addition: [A WinRT component implements the IInspectable interface, which derives from IUnknown ...](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2011/09/17/under-the-covers-of-winrt-using-c.aspx)

Answer (score 67):

From the [Build](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_%28developer_conference%29) keynote:

[image: Keynote stack]

They're providing common APIs to both HTML/CSS/JavaScript apps and C#/XAML apps. C# and XAML will be used, but it won't be WPF or Silverlight exactly.

Comment: This is a bit more involved, as the new XAML thingy is available to both C# and (native) C++. It's neither WPF nor Silverlight, but very close to the latter - as demonstrated on the keynote, you can often get away with merely changing a bunch of usings and other such trivial refactorings in existing Silverlight code. The core ideas behind WPF/Silverlight - declarative markup, resources, styles, templates, data bindings etc - are all there. Most controls are there also.

Comment: There's a better graphic out there that I saw this morning, but I just can't find it again. EDIT: Found, thanks to another answer on this question. http://dougseven.files.wordpress.com/2011/09/win8-new-platform.png

Comment: Where does WPF fit on the slide?

Comment: It's grouped together with .NET / Silverlight way at the bottom right.

Comment: That picture is grossly incorrect, as far as the existing pieces are concerned.  You can almost fix it by replacing "Windows Kernel Services" with "Win32 kernel32.dll" and "Win32" with "Win32 user32.dll+gdi32.dll"... but IE and .NET/Silverlight should be layered mostly on top of user32.dll+gdi32.dll, and those as well as C/C++/Java/Delphi/etc also reach down to kernel32.dll.  What's important is that user32.dll and gdi32.dll do NOT underlie WinRT, and that Windows Store Apps cannot reach past WinRT straight to the full power of kernel32.dll.

Answer (score 37):

The key idea is that now there is two development tracks - the Desktop and Metro.

- The desktop is where the old apps live.
- The new class of applications, Metro applications, can be built in a number of ways, including by VB.NET, C# or C++. These three language options can use XAML for building the UI. The alternative is to use JavaScript/HTML5/CSS for the development of both the UI and application code.

Some important points:

- Windows 8 feels sort of like an upscaled mobile phone OS.
- In Metro, there are no overlapping top-level windows, just as there are none on a mobile phone. If you want an MDI style application, you need to stay on the desktop.
- Metro style apps are automatically suspended when not visible. This was done to prolong battery life. This means it won't make sense for many existing desktop apps, which perform background processing even while the user is not interacting with them, to be ported to Metro.
- The ARM version of Windows 8 will not support desktop applications. So if you want to write an app and you want it to work on any version of Windows then it has to be a Metro app.

Comment: In Metro, there are no overlapping _top-level_ windows. There's still `Popup` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.popup), so if you want, you can cook up something MDI-like. Obviously not recommended to abuse it since you risk ending up with a non-touch-friendly UI.

Comment: @Pavel - that's interesting - does that mean you can have a couple of top level windows running side by side, but not overlapping? e.g. tiled ... sharing half the screen each for example? The WPF app I'm working on now needs this sort of functionality.

Comment: Every Metro app only has one top-level window. You can have two Metro apps running side by side, but this is something that user decides - there's no way for app to force itself into this configuration. Furthermore, even if you have two apps running side by side, they cannot communicate to coordinate (except through explicit user gestures such as "Share To").

Comment: On the other hand, you can, of course, subdivide your own single top-level window into as many areas as you want, and provide a movable divider to resize them - which, from user's perspective, would look like two tiled top level windows. They would still show up as a single thing in app switcher, though (but then you'd probably want it to?).

Comment: @Pavel "if you have two metro apps running side by side, they cannot communicate to coordinate" -- won't they be able to use some form of interprocess communication, via either .NET or native mode? E.g. MemoryMappedFiles, etc.

Comment: According to Martyn Lovell, there isn't any deliberate mechanism for that, and some that could be used for it are intentionally restricted. Named pipes aren't there, for example, nor are memory mapped files. There are sockets (including server sockets), but when connecting to `localhost`, you can only connect to the same app. You could use normal files in one of the shared "known folders" (Documents, Pictures etc), but that is a fairly crude hack that necessitates polling and is visible to the user.

Answer (score 24):

There's modified version of the architecture that'll surely help you understand where exactly the things lies. One of the Telerik ninjas had chat with the [CLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime) team and modified the picture:

[image: Windows 8 Platform and Tools (including the CLR)]

Here you can see where the CLR stands. The .NET framework now has two profiles

1- .NET Metro profile (CLR that deal with Metro application)

2- .NET Client profile (CLR runtime for C# and VB.NET applications)

I hope this gives you a clearer picture. Read the full article in *[A bad picture is worth a thousand long discussions.](http://dougseven.com/2011/09/15/a-bad-picture-is-worth-a-thousand-long-discussions/)*.

Answer (score 17):

Lots of detail from Microsoft [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464947%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

> The Windows Runtime is exposed using API metadata (.winmd files). This is the same format used by the .NET framework (Ecma-335). The underlying binary contract makes it easy for you to access the Windows Runtime APIs directly in the development language of your choice. The shape and structure of the Windows Runtime APIs can be understood by both static languages such as C# and dynamic languages such as JavaScript. IntelliSense is available in JavaScript, C#, Visual Basic, and C++.

In short, Windows Runtime is a new set of libraries exposing Windows functionality and available to JavaScript/C#/VB/C++.  Each language has been made to understand and be able to call them directly rather than having to go through some thunking layer.

Silverlight and WPF are flavors of XAML that run on the CLR.  Among other functionality, Windows Runtime exposes a version of XAML very similar to Silverlight, but does so in a native way, not via the CLR.  It can be accessed from the CLR, but also from C++.

Comment: The "thunking layer" may be present - e.g. CLR actually uses RCWs - but it is an implementation detail now. From dev perspective, you directly reference WinRT .winmd files, and work directly with the types inside.

Comment: While the thunking layer does use RCWs, the RCWs for the windows runtime are more lightweight than the old P/Invoke RCWs.