# Native C++ and Windows Tablets

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2012, tablet

I have a service application (no frontend) that was converted from C# to CPP native code not implementing .net framework.  This was done to speed the processing and to reduce the footprint.

I am investigating the move to support this service to Window tablet devices.  How would I go about this and what obstacles might I meet along the way?

TIA

Comment: do you mean Windows 8 tablets? Can you restrict the field to a particular area like GUI, networking, etc etc ... ?

Comment: Yes Win 8 Tablets - this is an internet monitoring process/service

Comment: An obvious obstacle is getting your hands on such a tablet.  They won't be available until summer next year.  At which point you'll probably find out that you can't build ARM code for it, that feature isn't being planned as of now.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't expect troubles, even Windows Phone 8 will introduce full support for the C++, there is no relevant news that can make you worried about Windows 8 and C++, the only relevant thing is the addition of the [WinRT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Runtime) to the usual set of C++ libraries for Windows but is more like an extensions rather than a set of libraries that will suppress something that is already existing in the Microsoft environment.

The only real changes are in the GUI subsystem, as you can expect just looking at the Windows 8 products and in this case under Windows 8, if you want a GUI, you probably do not have other options than switch to the [new WinRT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7418400/windows-8-c-and-metro-gui-samples).

There is also [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh700360) that can be useful.