# What is the Native Language for Metro Style Apps?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the new Windows 8 Runtime compare to Silverlight and WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416826/how-does-the-new-windows-8-runtime-compare-to-silverlight-and-wpf)

Is it JavaScript, C#, C++, or VB.NET?

Answer (score 3):

WinRT is implemented in COM, so C++ is the native language. .NET and JavaScript access WinRT through marshalling.

Here is a detailed answer: [How does Windows 8 Runtime (WinRT / Windows Store apps / Windows 10 Universal App) compare to Silverlight and WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416826/how-does-the-new-windows-8-runtime-compare-to-silverlight-and-wpf/7424103#7424103)

Comment: Thanks for the technical explanation.  I should've asked my question differently.  C# is the native/most widely used language when targeting .NET.  What language would this be for Metro Style Apps?

Comment: C# is the most widely used language for .NET, but it would not be correct to call it native. For instance, C++/CLI can access some capabilities of .NET that C# can't. Only time will tell which language will be the most popular for Metro apps.

Comment: @methym There's no "native language" for Metro style apps. WinRT libraries themselves are written in C++; but that should be irrelevant for you as a .NET developer, for example.