# How to add an Array in WinRT XAML

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml

I am looking to declare an array in XAML. I can do this in WPF. Just can't seem to find the right namespace in WinRT. Anyone know?

```
<Page xmlns:list="?Something?">

    <Page.Resources>

        <x:Int32 x:Name="MyScalarValue">123</x:Int32>

        <list:Array x:Name="MyValueList">
            <x:Int32>123</x:Int32>
            <x:Int32>456</x:Int32>
        <list:Array>

    </Page.Resources>

</Page>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

x:Array (and x:Static and a few other ones) aren't presently supported in WinRT.  For that matter, x:Array isn't supported in Silverlight either, [despite developers pushing for it](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/643058/support-x-array-construct-in-silverlight-xaml).

Given the fact that the XAML implementation for WinRT appears to be [more closely aligned with SL than WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935048/wpf-silverlight-vs-winrt), this isn't too surprising.

Edit - some more info regarding [SL4+ vs. WPF  differences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917841%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):
"Notable omissions here that exist in WPF or [MS-XAML] are x:Array, x:Code, x:Type, and code access modifiers."

Also, a delta between SL4 and the WinRT implementation [here](http://metroapps.wikispaces.com/Delta+with+Silverlight), and its associated links, makes it clear that these bits didn't magically make it into WinRT when they were (and still are) omitted from SL.