# Features of Silverlight 5 not in WinRT

Tags: silverlight, windows-runtime

I'm aware that a subset of WinRT is a modified Silverlight 5 as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9935294/870815).   As someone with knowledge about the Silverlight API it would be very useful to know what SL features are actually missing. I know about the [WinRT Genome Project](http://programmerpayback.com/2011/11/18/winrt-genome-project-details/), which tells me that it will be little - but not what it actually is. Wading through the difference lists is tedious and also potentially misleading, as some members or classes might simply be renamed.

Does somebody know of a concise list of missing SL features in WinRT?

Comment: Actually it shows the difference: http://timgreenfield.blob.core.windows.net/programmerpayback/Genome/SL5_WinRT/index.html

Comment: This is not a good way to go about it.  WinRT is a very basic redesign of the native Windows interface.  They made things look as familiar as possible, supporting XAML and the language projection built into the CLR help a lot.  But just about *all* .NET classes are affected, even core ones like System.String.  Too many differences to list.

Comment: @Passant According to the WinRT Genome Project, not a single one of the methods of System.String present in SL is missing in WinRT. The additions don't interest me at this point. Basically I'd be happy with the listings they provide if those would be more accessible (eg don't list additions) and accounted for renamers (which I know to exist). I made some simple porting tests from existing SL code and so far I found _no_ missing feature, so it can't be that much.

Comment: @ken2k That's the list I called tedious and potentially misleading in my question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://xamldialects.codeplex.com. That tool will allow you to actually explore the differences and similarities between any of the XAML dialects (WPF, SL, Windows Phone, and WinRT).

Comment: That's cool, I could certainly get my answer out of this tool as it comes with sources.