# Methods of sharing Information on Windows 8 Applications

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

I want to send the information to retrieve information from SMS listener.

Windows 8 Metro application does not support storing of information in XML file , SQL management studio. The only way is through Web service using SQL Azure. I can't do that because I'm not skilled enough to do so. Is there any other way to get information from 1 application to another? or 1 project to another project?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can a Metro app in Windows 8 communicate with a backend desktop app on the same machine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465517/how-can-a-metro-app-in-windows-8-communicate-with-a-backend-desktop-app-on-the-s)

Answer (score 0):

Metro apps can read and write XML files, the Windows.Data.Xml has APIs which let you read and write them.

If your application has access to the documents library, it can read and write files in the documents library.

You don't need a web service using SQL azure to save data from a metro app.