# How can I communicate a 4.5 framework based desktop program with an Universal App?

Tags: c#, udp, win-universal-app, communication, universal

I try to mirror what is happening on a desktop 4.5 framework based ( developed with Visual Studio) into an Universal App. For this I am trying to communicate with UDP but I cannot find the proper classes to do it. System.net.sockets is obsolete with Universal Apps and do not work. I try to use Windows.Networking.Sockets in the Universal App but the result is not good( I cannot connect both softwares) What I try to do is a real time communication( as fast as possible not needed a 100% accurate). Any suggestion is accepted not only UDP. Applications are run in different devices.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11156968/inter-application-communication-in-winrt

Comment: 4.5 framework is not winrt isnt it?

Comment: How about using StreamSocket, UWP sample here:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/StreamSocket-Sample-8c573931

Comment: I think no fast enough. I have chose udp based on speed not on reliability, i can lose some package but i want as fast as possible

Comment: Hans, I mean in different computers.

Comment: The frecuency of execution of the desktop application is 24 ms. The communication speed should be around 33ms