# Communication between desktop and metro app

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can a Metro app in Windows 8 communicate with a backend desktop app on the same machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465517/how-can-a-metro-app-in-windows-8-communicate-with-a-backend-desktop-app-on-the-s)

We have a long time developed desktop application in our company and trying to be updated, we wanna add Windows-8 support to it.

It is very hard for us to rewrite the whole application in Metro style, but we can simply use some of the Windows-8 new features such as **Live Tile**.

Trying to do this, it seems that we should develop a simple Metro app which communicates with dekstop application. Is there any standard way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metro (or Modern) applications are not supposed to have any dependency on any software being installed apart from themselves (ie. they're supposed to be self contained).  That being said, it is possible to bypass loopback prevention for the application and communicate with another application via a WCF service or sockets. See this [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/f980fedb-eb7e-4ff9-a3fc-a5ed8e1419ec) for more information.

As a direct answer to your question, I don't believe there is any standard way of doing this as it's not supposed to be done.

Comment: In addition to the reply above, please note that you only have the Desktop available in x86/x64 versions of Win8. In the ARM version you will not be able to use your application as there is no Desktop available.