# Interact with a separate program from within a Windows 8 Metro app

Tags: windows-8

I'd like to create a Win8 Metro app. To save having to write excessive amounts of code, I was wondering if I could interact with a non-metro program from within a metro app.

```
Metro app <----> External program
```

<sup>ASCII diagrams!!!</sup>

I have the source of several versions of this program in different languages (I can use any), and I can create my app in any of the Metro app languages (either C#, C++, or VB (guessing I wouldn't use JavaScript!!!))

So can I communicate this way?

Comment: You mean this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465517/how-can-a-metro-app-in-windows-8-communicate-with-a-backend-desktop-app-on-the-s

Comment: @user1731468 That would be one way yes. Thanks for the link.