# Can't use StreamSocket to connect to a TcpListener

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, tcplistener

I have an app on mobile devices who connects to my server app in desktops I use TcpListener on my desktop and TcpClient on mobiles. I tried to add support for Windows 8 but it seems Microsoft removed it and now we should use StreamSocket as TcpClient and StreamSocketListener as TcpListener. I tried to change my code but it is not even connecting to my TcpListener. (Note that I used asynchronous on desktops as well).

TcpListener on my desktop:

```
server = new TcpListener(Constants.DEFAULT_PORT);

server.Start();

server.BeginAcceptSocket(new AsyncCallback(OnAccept), null);
```

StreamSocket on my Windows 8:

```
var client = new StreamSocket();
await client.ConnectAsync(new EndpointPair(new HostName("localhost"), "7800", new HostName("localhost"), "7800"));
```

It passes the ConnectAsync line without being connected because my OnAccept on the desktop is not called.

So I don't know whats wrong here.

Comment: Yep! cause I'm just testing both on my machine and I have this machine only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Windows Runtime (store) apps cannot use networking to connect to localhost.  This web page talks about it:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh780593.aspx

I never was able to get localhost communication working using the above instructions, and opted instead to set up a listener on my local network instead.  Note that even local network access is turned off by default - you have to enable it via the application manifest for the Windows Runtime app.

Comment: It should also be pointed out that even by using the instructions in the link provided (not that I have tried) communication to another process on localhost is allowed only for development purposes, i.e. in Visual Studio.

Comment: You can find the solution in this other SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465517/how-can-a-metro-app-in-windows-8-communicate-with-a-backend-desktop-app-on-the-s