# TCP connection problems in Windows 8

Tags: tcp, windows-8, connection, installation

I have a small DLL that hooks into the spooler on windows platforms. It hooks the `StartDocPrinter` function, with the result, that every time a print job hits the spooler my DLL is called. This DLL worked fine on all platforms before windows 8.

The DLL are also able to hook into the windows 8 spooler.

The DLL makes a TCP/IP connection to a service, that can run on the local machine or on a remote server.

The problem is:

On windows 8 there are two "desktops", the native Metro desktop and a Windows 7 alike desktop.

If the service runs on the same machine and I submit a print job from the Windows 7 alike desktop the print job enters the spooler, the DLL is called and is able to connect to the service, but if I submit a print job from the Metro desktop (f.ex. select print from the Internet explorer), the print job enters the spooler, the DLL is called but is **not** able to connect to the service and recieves an `10060 TCP/IP errorcode`.
If the service is on a remote server submitting print jobs from both desktops works fine.

When running the service locally, I have tried to use both `127.0.0.1` and the machines own IPV4 address, but the result is the same when submitting the print from the Metro desktop.
I have tried to disable the firewalls, but that does not solve the issue.

Anyone who knows what could cause this behavior?

Comment: Metro (Windows Store) apps are restricted by Windows from connecting to localhost.  Maybe slightly different problem scenarios, but I think the answer is the same as this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410186/cant-use-streamsocket-to-connect-to-a-tcplistener/13410326#13410326

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I totally missed the network isolation part of windows 8 :-(

Comment: I have a few other observations that I would like to know if anybody knows the answer to.

I have tested the current process name when my DLL is called and in both scenarios, I have found it to be "spoolsv.exe" as expected. 
In the DLL the loopback connections fails when the print is submitted from a Windows Store App.

Another part of my solution is a port monitor, i.e. another DLL loaded by the spooler. 
This DLL also makes a loopback connection, and in this case it can make the connections even when the print job is from a Windows App.

Anybody have an idea why the later case works ?

Comment: That's an interesting one, I'm not sure why that would work. To get the most exposure, you really should ask a completely new question (and maybe provide more detail). If you found the answer in the linked question above useful, please upvote the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410186/cant-use-streamsocket-to-connect-to-a-tcplistener/13410326#13410326. Thanks.