# Send DataBase table via observable collection through WCF service and consume it in windowws Phone app

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps

I want to send an observablecollection object through a WCF service and receive it in windows phone 8 app. 
the service Is as below.

```
    public ObservableCollection<State> GetName()
    {

        StateEntities objEntities = new StateEntities();
        ObservableCollection<State> stateCollection = new ObservableCollection<State>();
        foreach (State s in objEntities.States)
        {
            stateCollection.Add(s);
        }
        return stateCollection;
    }
```

State is a Class having data from the table.  The contract is given below

```
   public interface IHost
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string DoWork();
        [OperationContract]
        ObservableCollection<State> GetName();
    }
```

Now I want to consume the service in a windows phone app. 
A button click should trigger the service consumption , get data from the service as observable collection and feed it into a gridview.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {

     ServiceReference1.HostClient proxy;

 public MainPage()
        {
            proxy  = new HostClient();
            this.InitializeComponent();            
        }

 private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            ObservableCollection<State> stateCollection = new ObservableCollection<State>();
            stateCollection = await proxy.GetNameAsync();
            dataGrid.ItemsSource = stateCollection;
        }
}
```

but it is throwing and exception in the await line.
This is the exception.

> An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: An error occurred while receiving the HTTP
>   response to "ttp://localhost:65338/Host.svc." This could be due to the
>   service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also
>   be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server

Can anybody suggest an alternative or solution ?

Comment: I'm guessing that Windows Phone (Windows Runtime) apps have the restriction that they cannot connect to other processes on localhost. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26531657/why-not-connect-from-winrt-appon-streamsocket-to-win32-appon-qtcpsocket) for a  discussion on the restrictions for Windows 8 (not phone) store apps.

Comment: no, that problem occurs when connecting to some other app. I am retrieving data from webService. Its not an app. I have successfully received a string. But objects and lists are not received. I was asking for possible ways to receive objects and collections.