# Windows Store Application unable to access localhost WCF service and throws EndpoingNotFoundException

Tags: wcf, windows-store-apps

I have a solution which basically contains three components:

• **WCF Service** that is hosted locally having a back-end SQL Server Express DB and this WCF service is hosted from a Windows Service
• A **console application**
• A **Windows Store Application**

---

This is what they are meant to do:

• WCF service his **hosted locally** and is used by the console app and the store app for communicating with the database
• The console app adds an image for processing to the database by contacting the WCF service
• The store app will at regular time look for unprocessed images in database via the WCF service and will process them

---

Now, **the difficulty is**:

• The WCF service is hosted successfully and is working absolutely fine and I can check that by hitting its URL http://localhost:8081/XYZ
• The console app is also able to submit images to the WCF service and add their local paths to the database
• **The store app however always throws the EndpointNotFoundException when accessing the service at that same localhost path**

---

What have I tried:

• I have tried almost everything from searching through stackoverflow to googling and haven't found a solution yet
• I was thinking that it might be a port issue and so I turned off the firewall to check this, but it did not work, and the store app kept throwing the EndpointNotFoundException

---

What have worked:

• The complete set-up has, however, worked perfectly on my machine. It is strange that its not working on my client's Windows 8 machine.

---

Point to be noted:

• The complete solution has been developed in Visual Studio 2013 and the App is for Windows 8.1
• I am not sure, but it seems my client has a Windows 8 machine and we are installing the app on that. (Possibly, that might be a problem. But I'll check)

**If there is any help someone could provide me, I'll be really greatful. Thanks in advance!**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why not connect from WinRT app(on StreamSocket) to win32 app(on QTcpSocket)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26531657/why-not-connect-from-winrt-appon-streamsocket-to-win32-appon-qtcpsocket)

Comment: The problem is likely that Win 8 disallows apps from communicating with localhost; Win 8.1 removes that restriction in certain scenarios.

Comment: @chuex You might be right in that respect and even I am having a same thought. Will discuss this with my client

Answer (score -1):

This is expected. Windows Store apps cannot connect back to the local system in production. This loopback prohibition is disabled for debugging.

See How to enable loopback and troubleshoot network isolation

If your app is to be side-loaded rather than deployed through the store then see Using network loopback in side-loaded Windows Store apps