# Why must StreamSocketListener be used in UWP instead of TcpListener, although UWP is a subset of .NET Core and TcpListener is available in UWP?

Tags: c#, sockets, websocket, uwp, windows-networking

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50042058/tcplistener-and-streamsocket) and [here](https://github.com/robertsundstrom/HttpListener), the usage of TcpListener ist not possible in UWP. Instead, StreamSocketListener has to be used.

But after a relatively long research, I didn't understand why?

Since UWP is actually a subset of of .NET Core, using TcpListener should be possible in UWP also!

Just for testing, I
even created a UWP project, tried to use System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener
in the code and there was no problem. I didn't write the complete code
and didn't try to run the server, but only tried to reference
System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener from within a UWP project and this was
possible. And no wonder because even according to Microsoft docs
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener?view=netcore-1.0)
the class is available starting from .NET Core 1.0.

Comment: "UWP is actually a subset of of .NET Core" is another typical misunderstanding. Though UWP/.NET Core shares many common pieces, they are different target platforms, and that's why only .NET Standard bridges them together.

Comment: Oh! so is this picture wrong https://i.stack.imgur.com/nl9gf.png ?

Comment: You might refer to latest diagrams such as https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-5/ You shouldn't expect a diagram to always tell all the truth, because the author might just be loo lazy to draw a separate rectangle for UWP.

Comment: Well, actually I didn't depend only on the diagram, I ran into the diagram in this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53531324/9514066 where the guy is saying explicitly that UWP is subset of .NET Core and he is using the diagram on purpose to illustrate his point

Comment: Then clearly that answer has been challenged immediately to be misleading, and Microsoft no longer uses such diagrams in their later official blog posts.

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of UWP support .NET Standard 2.0, which includes many APIs that were not available in earlier versions of UWP.

See eg: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-uwp-support-for-net-standard-2-0/

Comment: According to the docs (look at the link I mentioned in my question), TcpListener applies to: .NET Core 1.0. This means, it should be available in all UWP versions

Comment: @user9514066 You misunderstood that page. As you are using UWP, the only applicable item is ".NET Standard", which means if the UWP version your project targets has implemented a certain .NET Standard version, then `TcpListener` should work flawlessly there.