# Can a WinRT application access a COM outproc server on Desktop?

Tags: com, windows-runtime

Can a WinRT application access a COM outproc server hosted by Desktop application on same machine?

**Technical context**

- We are on x86/x64 Windows 8 (non ARM).
- WinRT application can be C++/WRL or C++/CX or .Net.
- COM outproc server is hosted by a .Net 4.0 or .Net 2.0 (two different versions) desktop app.

**Sub questions**

- Is there restriction on exchanged data?
- Is there examples availables?

Comment: I know about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465517/how-can-a-metro-app-in-windows-8-communicate-with-a-backend-desktop-app-on-the-s but its's not related to COM.

Comment: Is it a desktop app or a windows store app?

Comment: @SimonMourier The application hosting COM outproc server is a desktop app using .Net 2.0 or 4.0 (two different versions) and I need to access its COM components from a Windows Store app.

Comment: That's not possible, Store apps run in an "app container", a strong sandbox.  You can only run the code that's included in your app package.

Comment: @HansPassant That's what I was thinking. I have read about some socket limitation on WinRT: do you know if using socket or webservice is possible: server is opened from Desktop on 127.0.0.1 and WinRt connect to it.

Comment: That doesn't work either, same reason.  Local loopback can only be turned for testing, your shipping app *must* use an external server.