# Launching an Executable from WinRT?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-services, windows-runtime

Is there a way to do this?

Or at least download the executable and letting user open it?

I want to create a WinRT that depends on a desktop service like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465517/how-can-a-metro-app-in-windows-8-communicate-with-a-backend-desktop-app-on-the-s)

So either sideload the WinRT from desktop or install the desktop app from Metro.

Comment: Tsk, tsk, 43 votes for a completely invalid solution.  Local loop-back is *verboten*.  So is launching an EXE.

Comment: @Hans: I'm the owner and administrator, *I* decide what is forbidden on my computer.

Comment: Best suggestion I've seen is using Protocol Handlers.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465517/how-can-a-metro-app-in-windows-8-communicate-with-a-backend-desktop-app-on-the-s

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in WinRT today.  If you had an executable created for ARM Windows RT today, then you could run the app but Microsoft has not released any tools to create such an executable that runs as a desktop app on Windows RT.