# SendMessage not working for windows 8 metro apps using win32 lib

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I already know how to minimize any desktop app window from my win32 app in vc++ using SendMessage(). But it fails if that window is of Windows store app(Metro App). So which API to use for minimizing any windows store app window.
And it is different from the other question([question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465517/how-can-a-metro-app-in-windows-8-communicate-with-a-backend-desktop-app-on-the-s) because i am writing only desktop app. I just want a code to minimize any metro app window using vc++ win32 lib. And other question is about IPC between two apps where both apps are being written by us.

Comment: My question is no where near the question you are referring to be same. I dont know why you are not getting my question. Even if i am wrong somewhere, then i suppose this forum is about helping each other, not about down voting some one's question without even thinking what is being asked. I am asking one simple question that how to minimize any windows store app window in vc++, when we can minimize desktop window using SendMessage. I can't understand what is wrong with my question.

Comment: IPC is the answer. How else are you going to communicate between a desktop process and a store app process? You think you can use `SendMessage`? Which window handle will you use?

Comment: Not really a duplicate since the other is about IPC between a Windows Store app and a desktop app and this is about manipulating a Store app from a desktop app. Store apps cannot minimize themselves, so IPC won't help. If Shashank controlled both ends then IPC could be used to request the Store app to exit. Since Shashank wants to minimize any app that won't work. That said, there still isn't general purpose solution: desktop apps are blocked from manipulating Windows Store apps. An accessibility app could theoretically automate the CoreWindow to close, but that's a narrow use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some information how a Metro app in Win 8 may communicate with a backedn desktop app on the same machine here:

[How can a Metro app in Windows 8 communicate with a backend desktop app on the same machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465517/how-can-a-metro-app-in-windows-8-communicate-with-a-backend-desktop-app-on-the-s)

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, but i dont want to use IPC between my process and windows 8 app, I just want to send one simple message to any metro app window in the same way we send to any desktop app window using SendMessage to minimize the app, for example. So i just want to know about the appropriate API which i can use from my win32 app