# Windows 8 named pipe creation

Tags: named-pipes, windows-8, integrity

How I can create named pipe in the Windows 8 with AppContainer integrity level?

Comment: I think you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982221/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-named-pipe-from-an-appcontainer-bho-on-ie11

Answer (score 4):

As Pavel Minaev mentioned in one of comments to [some answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416826/how-does-the-new-windows-8-runtime-winrt-compare-to-silverlight-and-wpf/7426405#7426405), there are no named pipes in WinRT (for Metro applications, for desktop applications pipes are the same as in Windows 7):

> Named pipes aren't there, for example, nor are memory mapped files.
>   There are sockets (including server sockets), but when connecting to
>   localhost, you can only connect to the same app.

You may be interested in [the WinRT API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211377%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), including [sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.sockets%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: If sockets fit your needs, it is necessary to add the "Internet (Client & Server)" capability in Package.appxmanifest file. Double-click it and go the Declarations tab.

Comment: That's really not an answer, because question was about "Windows 8 with AppContainer" and answer is about "WinRT". It is possible to have desktop application in AppContainer integrity level, and named pipes are available for desktop applications in Win8. Unfortunately, I don't know how to create pipe, available to both High-integrity application and "AppContainer" app - I got "access denied", so the question is still open.

Comment: @Ezh thanks for a valid and argumented downvote. Please provide your own answer if you will find more information on this.

Answer (score 2):

Talking about WinRT - you really can't create named pipe.

Talking about Windows 8 desktop application running under AppContainer integrity level - you can create named pipe by regular WinAPI functions. The problem is by default only applications with same AppContainer ID could access it (in other words - only instances of your own application). But in fact if you have process under High or Medium integrity level - from this process you can create pipe and decrease its integrity level, so applications from AppContainer can use it.

Take a look at sample here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448493(v=vs.85).aspx

Even more - from desktop application with High integrity level you can use dll injection to inject you dll to WinRT application and again - use WinAPI to create pipes. So pipes are denied in WinRT not by OS design, but only by lack of interfaces in WinRT.