# Does Windows 8 Compile JavaScript?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

It is exciting that Windows 8 is supporting so many languages for Metro App development.  One that especially interested me was the HTML5/CSS/JavaScript.  What I don't understand, is this code going to get compiled in a sort of executable (like the C#, VB, and C++ option), or would my app basically be running in IE as an actual web page?

Comment: So how does it run in Windows 8 Metro Apps? In a slimmed down IE?

Comment: @GregPotter Yes, pretty much. It's "slimmed down" in a sense that there's no chrome other than what's standard for Metro apps. It's extended in a sense that you can load WinRT components (including your own custom one) and call them, which you cannot do in IE proper. But it is a browser, with DOM etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes.  Javascript is executed on Windows 8 by the Chakra engine.  Similar to the .NET just-in-time compiler, it translates javascript to optimized machine code.  Also the approach taken by Google's V8 and Mozilla's TraceMonkey engines.  Some background info [is here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/03/18/the-new-javascript-engine-in-internet-explorer-9.aspx).

Comment: To be clear, it is just-in-time compiled, but not pre-compiled. As in, you can't ship an app using JS without shipping the source code?

Comment: It is jutted, not compiled.  Unlike, Net code, it cannot be compiled (NGened)

Answer (score 2):

[Here's a video overview of some of how to use JavaScript with the new Windows 8 Runtime from BUILD2011](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/TOOL-533T) (slides also available on the same page). The presenter goes through a simple project with JavaScript and the WinRT and gives a pretty nice overview of WinRT in general. You can read more about all that [on this related SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416826/how-does-the-new-windows-8-runtime-winrt-compare-to-silverlight-and-wpf).