# Is it possible to build a html+js windows application without visual studio?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I'd like to connect my notebook to a heart rate monitor. I investigated a few days and I found that there is a GATT service in Windows applications I can use to do that. I found a great sample code here: http://www.getcodesamples.com/src/A6F3C0CA

As far as I can tell I have to compile this code somehow to make an executable. Is there a standalone compiler, or do I need to install Visual Studio? I don't want to use a different IDE for HTML + JS than Webstorm, and if there was a standalone compiler I could write gulp tasks to build the project easily.

According to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8659693/607033 the js is compiled with the Chakra engine. Visual Studio contains the compiler. I am looking for a standalone compiler I could use on a low memory machine.

Comment: @jpw Then what do you suggest how to run the code?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're actually looking for. https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Bluetooth-Generic-5a99ef95

It's the download link for the package you saw the sample of.

Comment: Thanks, but I already found that. I'd like to build without visual studio if possible. Actually this is a small tablet, I am not sure whether visual studio would be able to run on this. Webstorm requires 400MB memory, afaik visual studio needs 1-2GB, and the whole machine has only 2G memory.

Comment: I edited my question to avoid further misunderstandings.