# Where is IsolatedStorageFile in PCL for Universal Apps?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I started working on a *universal* app.

So, I created a new *Class library (Portable for Universal Apps)*. However, as soon as I tried to use the `IsolatedStorageFile` class, it said it was not there.

And indeed, searching for it in *Object Explorer* did not reveal such a class in the references for this project, which are the default for such a project: .NET (*.NETPortable, v4.6*) and Windows (*Portable,Version=7.0*). Targeting is set as *Windows 8.1* and *Windows Phone 8.1*.

According to the [IsolatedStorageFile page at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile(v=vs.120).aspx) it should be supported for *Windows Phone 8.1, Windows Phone 8, Windows 8.1*.

Actually, I can't see it in the references for the *Windows 8.1* and *Windows Phone 8.1* app that were automatically created for the *universal* solution, either.

Any idea how to use isolated storage in a *universal* app and what happened to `IsolatedStorageFile`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isolated StorageFile is for Silverlight apps. The equivalent for Runtime apps is StorageFile objects in ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.

See Accessing app data with the Windows Runtime (Windows Runtime apps): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464917.aspx

Comment: So, it appears there's WinRT, Silverlight and WPF, all being different enough to confuse me! I found more info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416826