# Is it technically possible to port Windows Store and UWP applications to Windows 7?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, cross-platform, windows-10, uwp

I will refer applications in Windows Store for either Windows 8/8.1 or Windows 10 as UWP applications as Wikipedia does, if I do not mistake it. Windows RT(not WinRT though) is not discussed to avoid confusion.

I wonder what API's no matter public or undocumented that Windows 8/8.1/10 have implemented that Windows Store and UWP applications rely on, so that they cannot be port to Windows 7, which is NT 6 as Windows 8/8.1/10 do.

If nothing much are there, but only due to M$'s market strategy to promote new technology'd Metro, there **might have been** some 3rd-party runtime/framework for Windows 7 on which Windows Store will work and UWP applications can run, which will surely spend no more effort and cause no more legal or compatibility trouble than **Mono** or **Wine**.

Edit: As [How does Windows 8 Runtime (WinRT / Windows Store apps / Windows 10 Universal App) compare to Silverlight and WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7416826/) says, it's a layer quite similar to .NET that lies between COM and application, if I didn't misread.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not a marketing strategy by the evil M$, and writing things like that makes you look rather juvenile. There's a *giant* layer of code (arguably an entire operating system within an operating system) that was written to enable Metro/Modern/UWP apps to run in Windows 8, tweaked in 8.1, and further refined in 10. That layer simply isn't there in Windows 7, wasn't backported, isn't going to be backported, and can't reasonably be backported by a third party who lacks access to the undocumented details of the implementation.

There is no conspiracy afoot here. It is a simple matter of new operating systems supporting things that old operating systems don't. The new features that Windows 8/8.1/10 have implemented that Windows Store and UWP applications rely on is the entire notion of a Windows Store and a UWP application.

The version number ("NT 6", as you point out) doesn't matter. All that tells you is they didn't massively rewrite the kernel. You don't have to rewrite the kernel in order to write a new layer on top of it.

If you want to run Metro/Modern/UWP/Store applications, you need to update to a later version of Windows. Alternatively, you can just write a regular Win32 application, which will run on all versions of Windows, including the latest builds of Windows 10.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. So you mean it is **technically** or **engineering** impossible to do it, right? (Some edits were made in question.)

Comment: Uh well, there are very few things in this world that are technically impossible. Some very enterprising team of hackers could probably come up with a UWP layer that would run on Windows 7. Ultimately, everything just calls down to native and Win32 APIs, so this is technically *possible*, but it is not technically feasible and it is legally dubious as well.